# Validation using angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-validation

Hi using angular 2 for password field I have to set " Password should have at least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 number, 1 special character, minimum of 8 characters, and maximum of 16 characters"

In that I have done "minimum of 8 characters, and maximum of 16 characters".

**But I am unable to set for remaining things least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 number, 1 special character.**

```
<div class ="form-group">
  <label> Password </label>
   <input class ="form-control" name ="password" #password="ngModel" [(ngModel)] = "angulaService.selectedAngula.password" 
   placeholder="password"  minlength="8" maxlength="16" >

   <div class="form-control-feedback"
   *ngIf="password.errors && (password.dirty || password.touched)">
  <p *ngIf="password.errors.required">Password is required</p>
  <p *ngIf="password.errors.minlength">Password must be min  8 characters long</p>
 </div>
  <div class="form-control-feedback"
    *ngIf="password.errors && (password.dirty || password.touched)">
    <p *ngIf="password.errors.required">Password is required</p>
    <p *ngIf="password.errors.maxlength">Password should not be greater than  16 characters long</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me in this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use async validators.

Comment: Is this for Angular 1.x or 2.x+? Please make sure you don't mix the tags.

Comment: @sundeep: Please correct the tags, they are mixed.

Comment: This is for Angular 2.x+

Answer (score 1):

Example of uppercase validator:

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import {NG_VALIDATORS, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, Validator} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[uppercaseValidator]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: UppercaseValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class UppercaseValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const value = control.value
    return /[A-Z]/.test(value) ? null : { uppercase: 'Must contain at least one upper case character'}
  }
}
```

Usage:

app.component.html

```
<form>
  <input uppercaseValidator [(ngModel)]="uppercase" #uppercaseCtrl="ngModel" name="uppercase"/>
  <div *ngIf="uppercaseCtrl.hasError('uppercase')">At least one character must be uppercased</div>
</form>
```

app.component.ts

```
<form>
  <input uppercaseValidator [(ngModel)]="uppercase" #uppercaseCtrl="ngModel" name="uppercase"/>
  <div *ngIf="uppercaseCtrl.hasError('uppercase')">At least one character must be uppercased</div>
</form>
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ws8sch)

Create other validators by following the same steps of creating a custom  validation directive. You just need to change the regexp and error message. You can use following regexp:

- uppercase: `/[A-Z]/`
- lowercase: `/[a-z]/`
- number: `/[0-9]/`
- special character: depends on what you consider a special character.

Answer (score 0):

Better use Regex for this,

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]
```

(you are already checking for min length and max length, so no need to put length limitation in regex, but you can still do that via regex. Although I would suggest keep both of the error separated.)